# How to unit test function having global variable using Chai Mocha and sinon?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon, chai

Consider this function,

```
    function upgradePlans (arr, curPlan) {
        var isPaidCustomer = cust && cust.type === "subscriber" && cust.subType === "paid";
        for (var i = 0, max = arr.length ; i < max ; i++) {
           if (isPaidCustomer) {
              if (plans_index[arr[i].planSize] > curPlan)) {
                 arr[i].upgradePlan = true;
              }
              continue;
           }
           break;
        }
        return arr;
    },
```

In this function, cust and plans_index are global object, test does not have access to these.

Now, i want to unit test this function that e.g

- It returns `arr` when `cust` is not defined
- It returns `arr` when `cust` is not subscriber
- It returns `arr` when `cust` is not paid subscriber

To solve this, i tried to change `upgradePlans` function this way,

```
   function upgradePlans (arr, curPlan, cust, plans_index) {
      // same content from above function
   }
```

To test function having global variable, i have to pass those variable as argument.

This solves the problem however requires a lot of changes in code.

Is there any other way to test the above function without changing in the code ?

Comment: What exactly do you want to test? All I can see from your example code is that you want to test if JavaScript property lookups work (which seems a bit superfluous).

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: Where exactly are `cust` and `plans_index` being set, though? You have to have _some_ code that will set their values, so why can't you use that code to set it before the actual test?